# Using git-shell and restricting developers to commit to their own projects

Tags: git

We are using `git-shell` to ensure that the git account is only used for git operations. This works great.

However before we move to using git full time, how do we set it up similar to github whereby depending on your public key you may only commit to your own repositories?

As far as I can tell the github people may be rolling their own `git-shell`, the [source code appears to be very simple to hack](http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=blob_plain;f=shell.c;hb=ff6d26a0e1d8fad775010fa3b689c0c027da8bb0)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I use something a bit simpler, all you need is to setup three files, the `authorized_keys` file, the `gitsecurity.rb` file and a permissions file `gitpermissions`. For simplicity they can all go in the git accounts .ssh folder. (Basic unix admin skills required to understand herein)

The `gitpermissions` file looks like this, and should be fairly self explanitory:

```
repo1.git|jane|rw
repo1.git|james|r
repo2.git|bob|rw
```

The `autorized_keys` file looks something like this:

```
command="/Users/git/.ssh/gitsecurity.rb jacob",no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-pty ssh-rsa rFaivBw.....5Rws jacob
command="/Users/git/.ssh/gitsecurity.rb bob",no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-pty ssh-rsa rFaivBw.....5Rws bob
```

Finally the `gitsecurity.rb` script, just copy and paste it:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

class GitPermission
    attr_accessor :username;
    attr_accessor :repository;
    attr_accessor :read;
    attr_accessor :write;

def initialize(line)
    bits = line.split('|');
    if(bits.length!=3)
        $stderr.puts "Invalid configuration file"
        Process.exit(4)
    end
    @repository = bits[0]
    @username = bits[1]
    @read = bits[2].include?("r")
    @write = bits[2].include?("w")
end

end

if(!ENV.has_key?("SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND"))
    $stderr.puts "SSH not allowed to the git account."
    Process.exit(1);
end
command = ENV["SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND"];

if(!ARGV.length == 1)
    $stderr.puts "Authorised keys file misconfigured, username not specified correctly."
    Process.exit(1);
end

if(!ARGV[0].match(/^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/))
    $stderr.puts "Authorised keys file misconfigured, username contains invalid characters: "+ARGV[0];
    Process.exit(1);
end
username = ARGV[0]

if(!command.match(/^git[ -]upload-pack /) && !command.match(/^git[ -]receive-pack /))
    $stderr.puts "Only git commands are allowed."
    Process.exit(2);
end

repository = command[(command.index(' ')+1)..-1]

if(!repository.match(/'.*'/))
    $stderr.puts "Repository parameter incorrect."
    Process.exit(2);
end
repository = repository[1,repository.length-2]

begin
    file = File.new("/Users/git/.ssh/gitpermissions", "r")
    while (line = file.gets)
        p = GitPermission.new(line);
        if(p.repository == repository && p.username == username)
            if((p.write == true || (p.read == true && command.match(/^git[ -]upload-pack/))) )
                exec "/usr/local/git/bin/" + command
                Process.exit(0);
            end
        end
    end
    file.close
rescue => err
    $stderr.puts "Problem with server configuration: #{err}"
    Process.exit(4)
end

$stderr.puts "You do not have permission to complete this operation"
Process.exit(5)
```

Comment: Thats cool, thats exactly what I was after, simple quick and easy. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

An option could be to use [gitosis](http://scie.nti.st/2007/11/14/hosting-git-repositories-the-easy-and-secure-way). (nice write-up [here](http://sunoano.name/ws/public_xhtml/scm.html#provide_a_git_repository_to_the_public))

Comment: Gitosis is great as long as you have access to install into the correct python locations, otherwise it is a nightmare.

Answer (score 2):

This script allows authenticated users can run arbitrary code under as the git user.

Example exploit: https://gist.github.com/ranmrdrakono/4959641
Suggested fix: https://gist.github.com/ranmrdrakono/4959672

Note that exec is given two parameters. The first one is the command to be executed (constant) and the second one ist the argument (which will not be interpreted by the shell).